# Visual Studio XML formatting messed up

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I have this problem present in various visual studio version I used over the past 3 years (2010,2013,2015) and I just can't solve it. My XML document formation messes up. The thing is that some XMLs are formatted just fine and some are not.

For example I want to have it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<MGL_Object>
  <rendering:MGL_IBLight
    name="ibl_tex_sunset_bg"
    texture_prefix="tex_sunset"
    rotation="-180"
    intensity="1"
    reflection_compression="1"
    dynamic_range_normalization="4000"
    gtr1="0"
  />
  <rendering:MGL_LightSetting
    name="light_settings_bg"
    use_ao="1"
    image_based_light="ibl_tex_sunset_bg"
  />
</MGL_Object>
```

But if I format document (Ctrl+K,Ctrl+D) I get this

```
<MGL_Object>
<rendering:MGL_IBLight
name="ibl_tex_sunset_bg"texture_prefix="tex_sunset"rotation="-180"intensity="1"reflection_compression="1"dynamic_range_normalization="4000"gtr1="0"/><rendering:MGL_LightSetting
name="light_settings_bg"use_ao="1"image_based_light="ibl_tex_sunset_bg"/></MGL_Object>
```

I just don't get it why.

Here are screen shots from before and after.

[image]

after

[image]

And also WHY some of the parts are underlined? I don't use any schema to validate XML!

Also while editing such underlined XML I have troubles as it is not well formatted on the fly and auto completion totally messes thing up.

Comment: Some things that I'd check (some of them may be obvious): File extension is .xml? Apply the formatting command from the menu, to make sure your shortcut is not redefined. Check the XML formatting settings under Tools > Options > Text Editor > XML. Start VS in safe mode (using `devenv.exe /SafeMode`) to make sure that there is no extension responsible.

Comment: File extension is .xml, Formating for xml under options are

[Formatting](http://imgur.com/a/6OX6s) and
[Miscellaneous](http://imgur.com/a/R0em8).

Also tried with /SafeMode. Doesn't help.

Comment: And you also formatted using the menu command (Edit > Advanced > Format Document)?

Comment: Yes. The same thing. I just tried to manually disable all extensions I have and the problem persists.

Comment: It is probably related to the error in your XML. When you move the mouse over the red squiggles you should see a tooltip with the error message.

Comment: I tried to clean text from any invisible non ASCII text and this still persist. If I how over underlined text I get these [underline](http://imgur.com/a/tRnzf). It makes no sense as I'm not using any XML Schema to verify against. Also the second picture reports invalid token at the root of document even though this is attribute.

Comment: There *is* one issue with your XML: You are using an undefined namespace prefix `rendering`. However, I do not think that this causes problems when formatting the document. My next best guess would be that VS is having problems with a byte order mark (BOM) at the beginning of your file. Open your file with a hex editor such as HxD and check if there are two additional bytes at the beginning. If so, remove those and check again.